# How to increment private variable in Model?

Tags: ios, xcode

In my struct Main Model (MainModel.swift):

```
private var charLevel: Int = 1

mutating func setCharLevel(_ value: Int) {
     charLevel = value
}

var getCharLevel: Int? {
     get {
          return charLevel
     }
}
```

In my firstViewController.swift:

```
private var MyModel = MainModel()
let sb = UIStoryBoard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

@IBAction func addLevel(_ sender: UIButton){
     if let secondVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondViewController {
          self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

          let charNewLevel = MyModel.getCharLevel! + 1
          MyModel.setCharlevel(charNewLevel)
     }
}
```

The SecondVC has only one label that shows charLevel from MainModel.swift and a button with self.dismiss that returns to firstViewController. So it just goes in a loop / circle. My problem is the level only goes to 2, even if I do 3+ runs, what am I missing? I would like it to increment by 1 every run (1st run: 2, 2nd run: 3, 3rd run: 4 and so on). Thank you from a learning student.

EDIT:

firstViewController -> ViewController (original name)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var battleDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heroHealthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var enemyHealthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var byBattleDescription: UILabel!

    private var QuestModel = MainModelQuest()

    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        QuestModel.setHeroHealth(1000)
        QuestModel.setHeroMaxHealth(1000)
        QuestModel.setEnemyHealth(150)

        if let initialTempHeroHealth = QuestModel.getHeroHealth {
            checkHeroLabel = initialTempHeroHealth
        }

        if let initialTempEnemyHealth = QuestModel.getEnemyHealth {
            checkEnemyLabel = initialTempEnemyHealth
        }
    }

    var checkHeroLabel: Int {
        get {
            return Int(heroHealthLabel.text!)!
        } set {
            heroHealthLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    var checkEnemyLabel: Int {
        get {
            return Int(enemyHealthLabel.text!)!
        } set {
            enemyHealthLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func attackOption(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let tempHeroRandomX = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
        let tempHeroRandomY = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1

        let tempEnemyRandomX = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1
        let tempEnemyRandomY = arc4random_uniform(5) + 1

        if tempHeroRandomX == tempHeroRandomY {
            battleDescription.text = "Hero's attacked missed."
            QuestModel.setHeroDamage(0)
        } else {
            if let chosenAttack = sender.currentTitle {
                switch chosenAttack {
                case "Attack1":
                    // 30 - 40
                    let tempHeroRandAttack = arc4random_uniform(11) + 30
                    QuestModel.setHeroDamage(Int(tempHeroRandAttack))
                case "Attack2":
                    // 20 - 30
                    let tempHeroRandAttack = arc4random_uniform(11) + 20
                    QuestModel.setHeroDamage(Int(tempHeroRandAttack))
                case "Attack3":
                    // 10 - 20
                    let tempHeroRandAttack = arc4random_uniform(11) + 10
                    QuestModel.setHeroDamage(Int(tempHeroRandAttack))
                case "Attack4":
                    // 1 - 10
                    let tempHeroRandAttack = arc4random_uniform(10) + 1
                    QuestModel.setHeroDamage(Int(tempHeroRandAttack))
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if tempEnemyRandomX == tempEnemyRandomY {
            byBattleDescription.text = "The enemy's attacked missed"
            QuestModel.setEnemyDamage(0)
        } else {
            let tempEnemyRandAttack = arc4random_uniform(11) + 10
            QuestModel.setEnemyDamage(Int(tempEnemyRandAttack))
        }

        if QuestModel.getEnemyDamage! > QuestModel.getHeroHealth! {
            QuestModel.setHeroHealth(0)

            if let heroKilledVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HeroFaintedVC") as? ThirdViewController {
                self.present(heroKilledVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            let heroDamage = QuestModel.getHeroHealth! - QuestModel.getEnemyDamage!
            QuestModel.setHeroHealth(heroDamage)
        }

        if QuestModel.getHeroDamage! > QuestModel.getEnemyHealth! {
            QuestModel.setEnemyHealth(0)

            if let enemyKilledVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EnemyFaintedVC") as? SecondViewController {
                self.present(enemyKilledVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

                let checkTotalExpi = QuestModel.getHeroExpi! + 30

                if checkTotalExpi >= QuestModel.getHeroMaxExpi! {
                    let heroNewLevel = QuestModel.getHeroLevel! + 1
                    QuestModel.setHeroLevel(heroNewLevel)

                    let newHeroMaxExpi = QuestModel.getHeroMaxExpi! * 2
                    QuestModel.setHeroMaxExpi(newHeroMaxExpi)
                    QuestModel.setHeroExpi(0)
                }

                enemyKilledVC.infoObject = QuestModel.getHeroLevel
            }
        } else {
            let enemyDamage = QuestModel.getEnemyHealth! - QuestModel.getHeroDamage!
            QuestModel.setEnemyHealth(enemyDamage)
        }

        if QuestModel.getHeroDamage! > 0 {
            if QuestModel.getEnemyHealth! <= 0 {
                battleDescription.text = "Hero dealt \(QuestModel.getHeroDamage!) damage and the enemy fainted."
            } else {
                if let attackName = sender.currentTitle {
                    battleDescription.text = "Hero used " + attackName + " and dealt \(QuestModel.getHeroDamage!) damage."
                }
            }
        }

        if QuestModel.getEnemyDamage! > 0 {
            if QuestModel.getHeroHealth! <= 0 {
                byBattleDescription.text = "the enemy dealt \(QuestModel.getEnemyDamage!) and the hero fainted."
            } else {
                byBattleDescription.text = "Enemy attacked and dealt \(QuestModel.getEnemyDamage!) damage."
                checkHeroLabel = QuestModel.getHeroHealth!
                checkEnemyLabel = QuestModel.getEnemyHealth!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainModel -> MainModelQuest (original name)

```
import Foundation

struct MainModelQuest {


    // Hero Properties
    private var heroHealth: Int?
    private var heroMaxHealth: Int?
    private var heroMana: Int?
    private var heroMaxMana: Int?
    private var heroStamina: Int?
    private var heroMaxStamina: Int?
    private var heroLevel: Int = 1
    private var heroDamage: Int?
    private var heroMaxDamage: Int? // Not yet used
    private var heroExpi: Int = 25
    private var heroMaxExpi: Int = 30
    private var heroGold: Int? // Not yet used
    private var heroGainedGold: Int? // Not yet used

    // Enemy Properties
    private var enemyHealth: Int?
    private var enemyDamage: Int?
    private var enemyLevel: Int? // Not yet used

    mutating func setHeroHealth(_ value: Int) {
        heroHealth = value
    }

    mutating func setHeroMaxHealth(_ value: Int) {
        heroMaxHealth = value
    }

    mutating func setHeroLevel(_ value: Int) {
        heroLevel = value
    }

    mutating func setHeroDamage(_ value: Int) {
        heroDamage = value
    }

    mutating func setHeroExpi(_ value: Int) {
        heroExpi = value
    }

    mutating func setHeroMaxExpi (_ value: Int) {
        heroMaxExpi = value
    }

    mutating func setEnemyHealth(_ value: Int) {
        enemyHealth = value
    }

    mutating func setEnemyDamage(_ value: Int) {
        enemyDamage = value
    }

    var getHeroHealth: Int? {
        get {
            return heroHealth
        }
    }

    var getHeroMaxHealth: Int? {
        get {
            return heroMaxHealth
        }
    }

    var getHeroLevel: Int? {
        get {
            return heroLevel
        }
    }

    var getHeroDamage: Int? {
        get {
            return heroDamage
        }
    }

    var getHeroExpi: Int? {
        get {
            return heroExpi
        }
    }

    var getHeroMaxExpi: Int? {
        get {
            return heroMaxExpi
        }
    }

    var getEnemyHealth: Int? {
        get {
            return enemyHealth
        }
    }

    var getEnemyDamage: Int? {
        get {
            return enemyDamage
        }
    }
}
```

SeconfViewController

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var infoObject: Int? {
        didSet {
            enemyDefeatedObject.text = "Lv. " + String(infoObject!)
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var enemyDefeatedObject: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // Return to map
    @IBAction func BacktoMapVC(_ sender: Any) {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        if let mapVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapVC") as? MapViewController {
            self.present(mapVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I understand that this may be a little bulk of code but this completes what I have been practicing so far, I may have incorrect conventions here but you are more than welcome to correct me on those point. My problem is upon running the program the 1st time, it gets correct level which is 2, 2nd run and conceding runs after are still two. Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks you.

Comment: In my observation, the first run shows two, and thats correct, but when its my 2nd run, it still shows 2.

Comment: can you show the rest of the firstViewController?

Comment: I think I can, but it may be a little different because I have revised the variable and function names above to make it a little clearer. this is in accordance to my mini game app.

Comment: what exactly of all of those modifications does not work?

Comment: moreover, in this case I would reconsider using `class` instead of `struct`, because it seems that in this case you require sharing of state (which is implicit in classes), and considering how often you modify the state of model, I think you don't have to worry about the performance overhead of classes.. Moreover, you would be able to drop the ugly setters and getters..

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I think whenever the Modal is loaded, it just resets the heroLevel to 1. I'm guessing this happens, in the event it  reads ViewController. Thats my guess why it just goes to level 2 and not proceed to level 3 and above.

Comment: so setting health and other properties works?

Comment: In my knowledge, yes, other properties works fine.

Comment: so while level gets set to two and does not go higher, expierence grows as it should? because from what you are saying it seems that the problem is not in the setter, but I would say that when going further you reset your model when you go back to your main VC and thats why when you again show level up, it shows 2 (because it was reset to 1, and then you increment it by 1).. if expierence and properties get reset, then you have your answer

Comment: I see. With this. Should I switch over to class instead of struct or there can be alternative solution?

Comment: you have to debug to find what causes the reset.. if it is reset.. that's just my hypothesis. but if it is a reset by directly setting the level back to 1, then changing to class won't help, because you will again reset it.. you have to find the root cause of this